# What does this code actually do and why should we have it included in our htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

Can someone please explain to me what this code does and why it does it.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s[^\s]*/{2,} [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- If the request is an uppercase word followed by a non-blank string and at least 2 slashes, e.g. "`GET something.php//do-not-care`"
- or the request hostname does not start with www
- and the request hostname is `(www.)(theRest)` where the `www.` bit is optional and keep the `theRest` as %2
- The replace the request by hostName by `www.theRest`.  The variable `%{REQUEST_URI} is just everything after the third slash in the request`http://somedomain/somerequest`.

In otherwords if the domain doesn't include `www.` then do a temporary redirect to the same but with the `www.`

Whoever wrote this wasn't experienced in writing these rules.